# Generate an array of weeks since 2017 till now using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to list week array from 2017 till now. My week start from Monday and ends with Sunday I tried to do in moment.js,

```
const startDate = moment().isoWeekday('Monday').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
const endDate = moment().isoWeekday('Sunday').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I tried to like this to get the week start date and end date but I don't know the process to next step.

**Note** my array list start with `["02-01-2017", "08-01-2017"]` and ends with current week will be the Last one.

```
const result = [["02-01-2017", "08-01-2017"],...... ["05-01-2018", "11-01-2018"]]
```

Comment: ["02-01-2017", "08-01-2017"] is this you input?

Comment: @rijin thank you reply no it not my input, I need to get the start week to date and end week date from 2017 till current week, i showed you the start date array of 2017

Comment: so, inputs are 2017 and monday => returns all mondays till today from 2017?

Comment: @rijin my week start with `Monday` and end with `Sunday`. I need all the week start date and end date till current week this will be my result `const result = {["02-01-2017", "08-01-2017"] .... ["05-01-2018", "11-01-2018"]}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can initialize your start date to 1st weekday of 1st January 2017 and iterate to all the dates less than today and keep adding days in an array.

```js
var weeks = [];
var startDate = moment(new Date(2017,0,1)).isoWeekday(8);
if(startDate.date() == 8) {
    startDate = startDate.isoWeekday(-6)
}
var today = moment().isoWeekday('Sunday');
while(startDate.isBefore(today)) {
  let startDateWeek = startDate.isoWeekday('Monday').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  let endDateWeek = startDate.isoWeekday('Sunday').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  startDate.add(7,'days');
  weeks.push([startDateWeek,endDateWeek]);
}
console.log(weeks)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great it working for me but i need up to current week right now i getting up to prev week start date and end date only is it possible to show up to current week?

Comment: Updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that would help?

```
let startDate = moment('2017-01-01').startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let endDate = moment(new Date()).startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const weeks = [];
while (startDate <= endDate) {
  weeks.push(startDate);
  startDate = moment(startDate).add(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}

console.log('weeks:', weeks);
```